# PHP's 'gzuncompress' function in C#?

Tags: c#, php

PHP's 'gzuncompress'  function in C#？
Is there a function similar to PHPs  gzuncompress in C#?

Comment: There ain't no functions in C#

Comment: @archil the C# language doesn't have functions? wow, that's weird....

Comment: Point that I was trying to say is that they are more called Methods than functions in object oriented languages. Weird phrasing from my side, I must say

Answer (score 2):

You would use a [`GZipStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) to read over the data. This is especially convenient if the source is itself a `Stream`, but if you have a `byte[]`, just use a `new MemoryStream(existingData)`:

```
private static byte[] GZipUncompress(byte[] data)
{
    using(var input = new MemoryStream(data))
    using(var gzip = new GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using(var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        gzip.CopyTo(output);
        return output.ToArray();
    }
}
```

and also:

```
private static byte[] GZipCompress(byte[] data)
{
    using(var input = new MemoryStream(data))
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var gzip = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            input.CopyTo(gzip); 
        }
        return output.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Note also that the "inflate"/"deflate" methods will be similar, but using a `DeflateStream`.

Note that I'm only using `byte[]` methods here for convenience; you should generally prefer the `Stream`-based API, since that scales to large data much more conveniently.